# Synchronise pdf to Rnw in Knitr with texshop

Tags: latex, knitr

Would anyone know how to get synctex to work from the pdf to the Rnw in knitr with texshop?  It does work from Rnw to pdf. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I worked this out. Not tried on multiple .Rnw files.

1. In TeXShop Preferences, make sure your "Sync Method" is set as "SyncTeX (TeX ≥ 2010)".
2. On your Mac, make the directory "~/Library/TeXShop/Rscripts" and put the R file "patchKnitrSynctex.R" downloaded from https://github.com/jan-glx/patchKnitrSynctex in this directory.
3. Create an executable file "Knitr.engine" including the following shell scripts and put it in "~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/":

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
    # export PATH=$PATH:/usr/texbin:/usr/local/bin # already on my path!
    Rscript -e "library(knitr); knit('$1')"
    latexmk -pdf -pdflatex='pdflatex -shell-escape -synctex=1 -file-line-error' "${1%.*}"
    Rscript -e "source('~/Library/TeXShop/Rscripts/patchKnitrSynctex.R', echo=FALSE, encoding='UTF-8'); patchKnitrSynctex('${1%.*}')"
   ```
4. In R, install the package "patchDVI".
5. In your .Rnw file, add "% !TEX TS-program = Knitr" on the top line of the document. Also inside the .Rnw document somewhere around the top of the document add an R code chunk

   ```
   <<setup, include=FALSE>>=
    patchDVI::useknitr()
    … #any other knitr global setups
    @
   ```

Happy knitting!